# is there a declarative approach to have one's background image changed from the portrait to landscape version upon orientation change in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation-changes

Background - I have an iPhone/iPad app that has a background image in the main view.  I'd like to introduce a specific portrait and landscape image for this background image, which is in a UIImageView subview.

Question - is there a declarative approach to have one's background image changed from the portrait to landscape version upon orientation change in IOS?   For example through some file name convention approach?

*(i.e. or do you have to manually change the image yourself each orientation change in the view controller's didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard about such sweet opportunity. So I think you should manually reload images.